# Auto minimize monitor when focus is on code

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, logcat

What I like about XCode is that it **auto minimize the debug part** in case you start writing code and show it when you "run" the app.

I was looking for a solution for Android Studio (and IntelliJ IDE's in general) on how to do this but couldn't find any

[image: android studio auto minimize android monitor]

Answer (score 1):

No, there's nothing like that built into IDEA. (Maybe there is a plugin for that.)

If I remember correctly, then automatically changing the View has been discussed lots of times, but JetBrains' stance on this is, that it does more bad than good.
I support that opinion (Eclipse has always been driving me made with its concept of Views).

If I want to focus on text editing, then I just use Ctrl-Shift-F12 (Window -> Active Tool Window -> Hide All Tool Windows)

Comment: I made a macro and with hotkey on a mouse button. but since IntelliJ has 999 ways to customize stuff, I was wondering how come they didn't made this thing too...